# how to recalculate ip checksum after modifying one of the 16bit words?

Tags: networking, ip

Given an ip header with header checksum calculated, how can i efficiently recalculate checksum after modifying one of the 16bit words in the header?

Answer (score 1):

It's fully described in [RFC 1624](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1624).

Normally at SO a mere link is not an answer, but in this case it is.

Comment: If would recommend against 1071 which you linked, and also against 1141 which is slightly better, but suggesting a wrong equation. The one you're looking for is probably 1624.